# How to include constant terms in statsmodels VECM

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, forecasting, vector-auto-regression

I am experimenting with Vector Error Correction Models using the `statsmodels` package in Python. I am not sure how to correctly create a VECM model with two constant terms, one inside the cointegration equation, and one outside it (**unrestricted constant**).

The [user guide](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html#vector-error-correction-models-vecm) explains two methods for specifying deterministic terms in the VECM model:

1. Using the `deterministic` argument. Passing `deterministic = "ci"` adds a constant term **only inside** the CE (restricted constant). Passing `"co"` adds a constant term **only outside** the CE. It's possible to combine one constant term with one linear trend term, for example `"cili"` creates a constant & linear trend term in the CE only. It's not possible to use both `"co"` and `"ci"` according to the [documentation](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECM.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECM) for `vecm.VECM`. I have tried both `"co"` and `"ci"` and they indeed only create only one constant term, outside or inside the CE respectively.
2. Using the `exog` and `exog_coint` arguments to manually create & pass the deterministic terms outside & inside the CE respectively. For example, to create a constant term in the CE, the user guide suggests passing `exog_coint = np.ones(len(data))`. However, the documentation for the `vecm.VECM` function suggests the shape of `exog` and `exog_coint` must match the dimension of the endogenous variables passed to `endog`.

I have 3 endogenous variables. To try and include a constant term in both the CE and outside it, I have tried several approaches:

## Approach 1

Pass `deterministic = "co"`, and `exog_coint` as an `ndarray` of ones, for each endogenous variable, with the shape `(len(train), 3)`:

```py
# Create deterministic terms for each endogenous variable
exog_coint = np.array(
  [np.ones(len(train)), np.ones(len(train)), np.ones(len(train))]
)
exog_coint = exog_coint.transpose()

# Specify VECM
model_vecm = vecm.VECM(
  endog = train, # Endogenous variables, dataframe with 3 columns
  k_ar_diff = selected_lags, # Order of lags
  coint_rank = 1, # N. of cointegrating relationships
  exog_coint = exog_coint, # Constant term inside the CE
  deterministic = "co" # Constant term outside the CE
)

# Fit VECM
res_vecm = model_vecm.fit()

# Print summary
res_vecm.summary()
```

This approach yields the `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` error when trying to fit the model. From this, I assume the shape of `exog_coint` has to be `(len(train), coint_rank)` instead: One set of constants for each cointegrating relationship (just one in my case).

## Approach 2

Pass `deterministic = "co"` and `exog_coint = np.ones(len(train))`, passing only one 1D array of constants. The code for this approach is the same as above, except for creating `exog_coint`. This time, the model is fitted with no error, but trying to print the model summary yields the following error:

```py
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return np.sqrt(np.diag(self.cov_params_default))
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

`res_vecm.const_coint` returns a zero value, but `res_vecm.det_coef_coint` does yield a non-zero constant term. Problem is, this value is astronomically large: 5.2849e+19 compared to my endogenous variables mostly in the ten thousands. I do not know if this is correct. The fitted values and predictions seem fine, but the `vecm.select_order` function also does not work:

```py
# Select lag orders for VECM
res_lags = vecm.select_order(
  data = train,
  maxlags = 15,
  exog_coint = exog_coint, # Created as np.ones(len(train))
  deterministic = "co" 
)
```

```py
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 
2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

This error suggests some sort of mismatch between the endogenous variables argument (`data`) and the `exog_coint` argument, but the same arguments work fine in fitting the VECM.

## Approach 3

Do not use the argument `deterministic`. Instead, create & pass constant terms both outside and inside the CE, with arguments `exog` and `exog_coint` respectively.

```py
# Create deterministic terms outside the CE for each endogenous variable
exog = np.array(
  [np.ones(len(train)), np.ones(len(train)), np.ones(len(train))]
)
exog = exog_coint.transpose()

# Create one deterministic term inside the CE
exog_coint = np.ones(len(train))

# Specify VECM
model_vecm = vecm.VECM(
  endog = train, # Endogenous variables, dataframe with 3 columns
  k_ar_diff = selected_lags, # Order of lags
  coint_rank = 1, # N. of cointegrating relationships
  exog = exog, # Constant term outside the CE
  exog_coint = exog_coint # Constant term inside the CE
)

# Fit VECM
res_vecm = model_vecm.fit()

# Print summary
res_vecm.summary()
```

Like approach 1, this approach yields a `LinAlgError: Singular matrix` error when trying to fit the model. `vecm.select_order` also yields the same error as approach 2:

```py
# Select lag orders for VECM
res_lags = vecm.select_order(
  data = train,
  maxlags = 15,
  exog = exog,
  exog_coint = exog_coint
)
```

```py
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 
1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)
```

## Approach 4

Use `exog` and `exog_coint`, but pass a 1D array of `np.ones(len(train))` to both arguments. This approach fits the model without error, and yields the same fitted values, predictions & parameters as approach 2. It also yields the same error when trying to print the model summary. In addition, `vecm.select_order` yields the following error:

```py
# Select lag orders for VECM
res_lags = vecm.select_order(
  data = train,
  maxlags = 15,
  exog = exog_coint, # Created as np.ones(len(train)) 
  exog_coint = exog_coint
)
```

```py
ValueError: endog and exog matrices are different sizes
```

This is confusing, as the model seems to be fitted correctly as in approach 2, but the error message for `vecm.select_order` clearly states `exog` must have the same shape as `endog`.

So to sum up, here are my questions:

1. How to properly include a constant term both outside and inside the cointegration equation in a `vecm.VECM` model? Is this possible at all? It seems the VECM function from the R library [tsDyn](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tsDyn/versions/11.0.4/topics/VECM) takes two string arguments, one for deterministic terms inside the CE, another for outside.
2. How to properly use the `exog` and `exog_coint` arguments? What should be the correct shape for each?